# Send stored procedure parameter into subreport

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, reporting-services, crystal-reports

My main report is populated by a stored procedure based on one parameter. There is a sub-report in the group footer which requires the same parameter/value as the main report's parameter. The sub-report returns data linked on the group field, so the data returned is chunked between the matching groups.

I want to avoid giving both parameters the same value, but I can't find any way to use one for both cases. If I link the reports based on the parameter, the group chunk is lost and each group footer returns the entire sub-report. How can I properly use a single parameter?

The stored procedures are Oracle 9i SQL if that makes any difference.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't split a sub-report between group footers. You would need to pass the value the group is based on as another parameter to the sub-report in order to further filter the sub-report. Again, not sure whether this will work...

Comment: Gallus is correct. You'll probably have to rewrite the subreport to filter out based on group (so it doesn't display all the information.) Though you could pass the same value the Group uses as a parameter to the subreport.